Login in Play Station network on visionOS swift WKWebView
I'm trying to log in into a playstation account inside a WKWebView. After trying different configurations, I've managed to go through the full login form, but I always get an error (unable to connect to server or timeout); however, I don't think this is a server issue since I can perfectly log in on my desktop browser or even Safari inside the same device I'm trying my app on.
Here's how I create the WKWebView.-
let request = URLRequest(url: url)
let preferences = WKPreferences()
preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
preferences.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
preferences.isSiteSpecificQuirksModeEnabled = true
let userContentController = WKUserContentController()
userContentController.add(context.coordinator, name: "bridge")
            
let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
configuration.websiteDataStore = WKWebsiteDataStore.default()
configuration.userContentController = userContentController
configuration.preferences = preferences
let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration)
    
webView.customUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.3 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"
webView.load(request)

I'm pretty sure this might be a very simple configuration issue I just can't see (already tried setting a custom user agent, and enabling / disabling cookies and javascript), any idea of where the issue might be?
PS: I've tried playstation login and sony login with similar results.
EDIT
It's actually working on iOS, the issue seems happening only on visionOS, but still no clue of where might it be.

